# Using Ramda to group and transform items of an array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I need to group items from an array by  `batchNumber` and sum their values.

Currently I am using ramda, but I am able to group but not to transform the result.

Could you please provide me an example using ramda.js?

[Live Example](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batchNumber%3A%20%27a%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%205%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batchNumber%3A%20%27a%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%2010%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batchNumber%3A%20%27b%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batchNumber%3A%20%27b%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%207%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20byBatchNumber%20%3D%20R.groupBy%28%28batch%29%20%3D%3E%20batch.batchNumber%29%3B%0A%0A%0Aconsole.log%28byBatchNumber%28input%29%29%0A%0A%2F%2A%0A%0Aconst%20output%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batchNumber%3A%20%27a%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%2015%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batchNumber%3A%20%27b%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20batchNumber%3A%20undefined%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20scrapAmount%3A%2010%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%0A%0A%2A%2F%0A%0A%0A%0A):

```
const input = [
    {
        batchNumber: 'a',
        scrapAmount: 5
    },
    {
        batchNumber: 'a',
        scrapAmount: 10
    },
    {
        batchNumber: 'b',
        scrapAmount: 1
    },
    {
        batchNumber: 'b',
        scrapAmount: 2
    },
    {
        scrapAmount: 7
    },
    {
        scrapAmount: 3
    }
]

const byBatchNumber = R.groupBy((batch) => batch.batchNumber);


console.log(byBatchNumber(input))

/* result wanted

const output = [
    {
        batchNumber: 'a',
        scrapAmount: 15
    },
    {
        batchNumber: 'b',
        scrapAmount: 3
    },
    {
        batchNumber: undefined,
        scrapAmount: 10
    },
]

*/
```

Comment: Use this method:      `var result = [];
input.reduce(function (res, value) {
    if (!res[value.batchNumber]) {
        res[value.batchNumber] = {
            scrapAmount: 0,
            batchNumber: value.batchNumber
        };
        result.push(res[value.batchNumber])
    }
    res[value.batchNumber].scrapAmount += value.scrapAmount
    return res;
}, {});`

Comment: ```
R.map(
  reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc + curr.scrapAmount, 
    0
  )
)(byBatchNumber(input))
```

Comment: @NinaScholz: This does not look like a duplicate of that one, which is asking for a more sophisticated merging of objects.  This one can probably be handled with `pipe(groupBy(prop('batchNumber')), map(pluck('scrapAmount')), map(sum))`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, please add this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly simple version would be the following:

```js
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, sum} = R;

const input = [
    {batchNumber: 'a', scrapAmount: 5},
    {batchNumber: 'a', scrapAmount: 10},
    {batchNumber: 'b', scrapAmount: 1},
    {batchNumber: 'b', scrapAmount: 2},
    {scrapAmount: 7},
    {scrapAmount: 3}
]

const totalScrap = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('batchNumber')), 
  map(pluck('scrapAmount')), 
  map(sum)
)

console.log(totalScrap(input))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Note first that this simplifies `R.groupBy((batch) => batch.batchNumber)` to `R.groupBy(R.prop('batchNumber'))`; it' the same functionality, just expressed more concisely.

This is as far as I would go, because I believe this to be the most helpful output format for the work I usually do, namely something like this:

```
{"a": 15, "b": 3, "undefined": 10}
```

But rereading your required output, it might take two more steps:

```js
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, sum, toPairs, zipObj} = R;

const input = [
    {batchNumber: 'a', scrapAmount: 5},
    {batchNumber: 'a', scrapAmount: 10},
    {batchNumber: 'b', scrapAmount: 1},
    {batchNumber: 'b', scrapAmount: 2},
    {scrapAmount: 7},
    {scrapAmount: 3}
]

const totalScrap = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('batchNumber')), 
  map(pluck('scrapAmount')), 
  map(sum),
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['batchNumber', 'scrapAmount']))
)

console.log(totalScrap(input))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

One thing this doesn't do is to generate an item with `batchNumber: undefined`, and instead returns one with `batchNumber: "undefined"` (a string.)  While this could be fixed, it's an ugly step, and I don't see a real gain.  And likely solutions would then fail if you had one with a value of `"undefined"`.  If this is really a show-stopper, you could obviously process these before the last step in that pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

You [`groupWith()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith) by checking that the *batchNumber* is equal with [`eqProps()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqProps). Then [`map()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) each subarray, apply [`mergeWithKey()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeWithKey) to all objects, and [`add()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#add) the values of the *scrapAmount* field:

```js
const { compose, groupWith, eqProps, map, apply, mergeWithKey, add } = R;

const input = [{"batchNumber":"a","scrapAmount":5},{"batchNumber":"a","scrapAmount":10},{"batchNumber":"b","scrapAmount":1},{"batchNumber":"b","scrapAmount":2},{"scrapAmount":7},{"scrapAmount":3}]

const byBatchNumber = compose(
  map(apply(mergeWithKey((k, l, r) => k === 'scrapAmount' ? add(l, r) : r))),
  groupWith(eqProps('batchNumber'))
)

console.log(byBatchNumber(input))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```